# Initializing a static POSIX semaphore inside a class

Tags: c++

```
class Semaphore
{
    private:
        static sem_t sem_id;
}
```

in cpp:

```
sem_init(&Semaphore::sem_id, 0, 0);
```

obviously , the compiler won't let me run code outside of a function. But it's not a type that can be just initialized to a value. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the `sem_id` in your own class that performs `sem_init` on default-construction (and `sem_destroy` on destruction; don't forget that!).

Sadly, `sem_t` is not a class so you can't inherit from it and must instead compose it:

```
#include <semaphore.h>

class scoped_sem_t
{
public:
    scoped_sem_t() { sem_init(&sem, 0, 0); }
   ~scoped_sem_t() { sem_destroy(&sem); }

   sem_t& get() { return sem; }

private:
   sem_t sem;
};

class Semaphore
{
private:
   static scoped_sem_t impl;  // use Semaphore::impl.get()
};

scoped_sem_t Semaphore::impl;  // (don't forget this!)
```

<sup>(N.B. completely untested but I guess it *should* work…)</sup>
<sup>(Also, not the best example of class design, but gives you the gist.)</sup>

Otherwise, sadly, there are no ways to do this neatly. You could write the `sem_init` at the start of `main` instead, but be careful then not to reference `Semaphore::sem_id` from any other static initialiser.

Comment: so simple, should have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: @susdu: Just a bit of lateral thinking :)

Comment: Gah, `sem_t` isn't a class so you'll need to compose rather than inherit.

Comment: There. Made a bit more of a mess. Same basic idea though - use RAII to work around `static` non-initialisation initialisation problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can call functions from global scope just fine, as long as you do so inside an initializer:

```
int unused_garbage = sem_init(&Semaphore::sem_id, 0, 0);
```

For clean destruction, you can either use a global initializer to register an at_exit handler, or use proper RAII as LRiO's answer demonstrates.

Comment: Or that, but you can't do `sem_destroy` this way.